# How to display an empty view, progress view and datas in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

This is mainly a conceptual question. I am using a ListFragment in my Activity. Its list must display one of these information:

- A list of items
- An empty view if there is no items
- A "loading" view for when the datas are loaded from the database

The empty view is managed automatically by the framework because my ListFragment's on onCreateView is creating a custom view like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    if(Globals.DEBUG_LIFECYCLE)
        Log.d("Fragment", "ONCREATEVIEW");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.kanji_list, null);
}
```

The Layout of kanji_list is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ch.shibastudio.kanjinotepad.list.KanjiListEmptyView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/no_kanji"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The datas are stored in a SQLite database that is embedded in my application. When the application wants to update to ListView, a custom Loader is used to query the database and return a Cursor to the ListFragment. I use a custom Loader and not the CursorLoader because I don't want to create a ContentProvider.

So, **what I would like to do** is: *when the application start a query of the datas from the database, the "loading" view will be shown, showing a progress picture and a text saying something like "Getting datas". Then, when the Loader finishes its job, I want to display the queried datas in the ListView, or display the "empty" view if there is no data.*

I don't want to use a ProgressDialog for some reasons. So my question is: how to provide the "loading" view? Here are my first, rough ideas:

1. Replace the ListView by a custom view during the load of the datas and show the List when the Loader finishes its job

or

1. Use one Adapter for displaying the datas
2. Use another Adapter containing only one item that is the "loading" view
3. Set the right Adapter at the right time (when the Loader start its job: myList.setAdapter(mLoadingAdapter), when the Loader finishes its job: myList.setAdapter(mDataAdapter))

Any other ideas? Do you have any "good practice" hint to give to me in order to achieve that?

---

**I found the solution, thank you Kasra Rahjerdi and Harikris!**
Here is how I did it:

First, create a layout file for the ListView, empty view and the "loading" view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listcontainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            />

        <ch.shibastudio.kanjinotepad.list.KanjiListEmptyView android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/no_kanji"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ch.shibastudio.kanjinotepad.customviews.LoadingView android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is very important to create a container (here *listContainer*) for the ListView **and** the empty view. I tried to set the Visibility of the ListView to GONE and it automatically set the Visibility of the empty view to Visible. Looks like there is some internal code doing that for the ListView, so the solution was to put them in a container and showing/hiding it completely.

So basically, the idea is: When the datas are loading, I want to show the loading view, for that, I hide the ListView container by putting its Visibility to GONE (if I put the Visibility to INVISIBLE, it keeps the size of the list in the View, using GONE is like removing it completely and thus, the "loading" view can take all the screen) and showing the the "loading" view by putting its visibility to VISIBLE.

In my ListFragment, I got the references of these views like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kanji_list, null);
    mLoadingView = (LoadingView)v.findViewById(R.id.loading);
    mListContainer = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
    return v;
}
```

And I show/hide the "loading" view by calling this method:

```
private void setLoadingViewVisible(boolean visible){
    if(null != mLoadingView && null != mListContainer){
        mListContainer.setVisibility(visible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoadingView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `ListFragment` which comes with the support library, a copy [of its source code is here](https://github.com/grantland/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.java).

This class is different than the regular `ListFragment`, and the difference is visible in the `onCreateView` function. If you look at it, it offers exactly what you're describing.

1. It offers an animated loading spinner before the data is bound to it.
2. It displays whatever data you want to display in the adapter, just like a regular `ListFragment`.
3. It has an optional empty field which you can set by calling `setEmptyText()`

So I'd either recommend you use the support library's copy of `ListFragment` rather than the normal one, else use the source code I linked above as a stepping stone for making your own version of the class.

Comment: Thank you Kasra Rahjerdi, I will have a look at this source code to get inspiration.

Comment: I found the solution (will post it now) by looking at the source code in the link you provided. Thank you Kasra Rahjerdi!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific question related to your application working. Having said that, i think the best thing to do in your case is to have 3 views in your `fragment` layout file. `ListView` to show the list of items whenever the query is completed and the item count is non-zero. Another `ProgressBar` view to be used when the query is under progress. By setting the progress number (default is 0 to 100) you can control the visibility of this `ProgressBar` or if you are using an `indeterminate` style of ProgressBar you can control it's `visibility` by using the View's visibility. And finally a `Label` or `TextView` to be used when there are zero items to show - control the visibility of this View. `ListView` and `TextView` are mutually exclusive in your case meaning when `ListView` shows, the `TextView` is hidden. HTH

Comment: Thank you Harikris, your ideas also pointed me in the right direction. I posted my solution at the end of the question.

Comment: @Shibakaneki If it helped you, please up-vote when you get a chance. It will also help others that follow you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like the list to contain a loading message without blocking the user.  I presume you have figured out some way to asynchronously update the list when the data fetching has finished.

Anyway, there are a couple approaches that come to mind.

The simplest is probably to have three views in your linear layout and hide two of them, only exposing the one that has something to show.  For example, while loading you would hide id/android:list and expose the view that says "loading...".  Once loading is done, you would hide "loading..." and unhide the list or the "empty" view.

The other approach is to use three kinds of list items.  Take a look at [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).  Subclass Adapter (or whatever variant of it you are using) and define getViewTypeCount to return 3.  Then define getItemViewType to return one of three values, depending on what you want to display.  Finally, enhance getView (you must already have a version of this function) to return three types of views.

Comment: I like the idea of another view in the Layout and hide the ListView during the load, thank you for the idea, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create your empty view inclusive ListView in **onCreateView**.

Then in **onStart** show your ProgressBar. Now start a thread, else your ProgressBar may not be shown because the following code runs on the main thread. In this thread, you load your data, show it and dismiss the ProgressBar.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, container, false);

        return view;
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ProgressBar
    new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),
            getString(R.string.loading_title),
            getString(R.string.loading_msg), true, false);

    // get ListView
    final ListView myListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.listView1);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //load your data here (fill Adapter)!
            loadData();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // fill ListView, dismiss Dialog
                    myListView.setAdapter(yourAdapterWithData);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    thread.start();
}
```

This ist just example code, it wont work correctly...

Comment: Thank you Manu for your answer. However, as I said in my question, I don't want to use a Dialog. But the solution you propose can be a good idea for another application.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read you wanted to use a Dialog... My fault. The idea is still the same: Create a view (picture in your case), start a thread, as soon as it finishes you can change the view. [br] This may help

Comment: A solution would be to declare 2 views in 2 xml-files, and then switch them. Described on [this website](http://www.aslingandastone.com/2010/dynamically-changing-android-views/)